# Custom Search API - search with image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-custom-search

I see this question was asked few times but looks like API changed a lot and most answers seem to be out of date.

I want to use image URL to search for similar ones.

API is using my [CSA](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/creatingcse)
where I enabled "Search by image". That kinda implies that this should work?
Putting URL in search query returns results but those are based on URL wording, not content of it.

[Full code](https://github.com/Landsil/unsplash_search/blob/master/search_google.gs) in case anyone needs it.

Relevant part:

```
  var BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?searchType=image&siteSearch=unsplash.com&siteSearchFilter=e",
  query = unsplash_search.getRange("F1").getValue(),
  URL = `${BASE_URL}&key=${google_key}&cx=${cseID}&q=${query}`;
```

query = normal URL there.

Comment: Please post relevant sections of code and mention what has already been tried

Comment: added request URL I'm using,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a *Reverse Image Search*, like you would via the UI like this:

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

Unfortunately, the [Programmable Search Engine does **not** support this feature](https://support.google.com/programmable-search/thread/6328018).

However, if this is important for you, you could file a Feature Request by going here:

[image: send feedback]

Comment: looks like I've missed manual for "enable image search" it just searches FOR images :sob:

https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/2630972?hl=en&ctx=topic&topic=2568895

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the Cloud Vision API for this: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web

Comment: Yup, I was afraid I will have to.